# NoSuchElementException error

Tags: java, runtimeexception, stringtokenizer, nosuchelementexception

I am trying to see if the next token in a string is equivalent to map key, and adding a message to an array list.

```
ArrayList<String> trace = new ArrayList<String>();
if(!element.startsWith("PRINT")) {
            while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                tokens.add(st.nextToken());
            }

            for(String key: expression.keySet())
                if(st.nextToken() == key)
                    trace.add(key + "Changed from " + expression.get(key) + " to " + tokens.get(2));

            expression.put(tokens.get(0),Integer.parseInt(tokens.get(2)));
            tokens.clear();
}
```

ERROR MESSAGE

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)
    at Commander.main(Commander.java:45)
```

Comment: Replace if(st.nextToken() == key) with if(st.hasMoreTokens() && st.nextToken() == key), i think it would solve your problem.

Comment: Outside of the fact that you can't compare strings with `==` (which is what `st.nextToken() == key` is doing; don't do that), you don't specify what your tokenizer is breaking things up by, nor do you specify what your initial input string is.

Comment: You shouldn't use [`StringTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), the Javadoc reads (in part) *`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String` or the `java.util.regex` package instead.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with `st.nextToken()` call.

You are checking `st.hasMoreTokens()` only once but calling `st.nextToken()` twice. And it is throwing the error.

During 1st `while` loop you are reading all the tokens:

```
while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    tokens.add(st.nextToken());
}
```

Since 'all' the tokens are already read, now when you try to read the token again inside the `for` loop you will get the error.

```
if(st.nextToken() == key) {
    trace.add(key + "Changed from " + expression.get(key) + " to " + tokens.get(2));
}
```

There is also another potential problem. You are trying to convert the 3rd token to an Integer. It might fail there as well:

```
// Value of tokens.get(2) is "string"
Integer.parseInt(tokens.get(2))
```

You will get error here also. It would be good to check if `tokens.get(2)` is of numeric type or not. like:

```
int value = 0;
if (StringUtils.isNumeric(tokens.get(2))) {
    value = Integer.parseInt(tokens.get(2));
}
// Default value will be 0.
expression.put(tokens.get(0), value);
```

Reference: [StringUtils.isNumeric()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNumeric%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

So, the modified code will be like:

```
ArrayList<String> trace = new ArrayList<String>();
if(!element.startsWith("PRINT")) {
    List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        tokens.add(st.nextToken());
    }

    // Size of tokens has to be more then 3, otherwise you will get another error.
    if (tokens.size() >= 3) {
        for(String key: expression.keySet()) {
            if(tokens.get(0).equals(key)) {
                 // Do your other operations...
                 trace.add(key + "Changed from " + expression.get(key) + " to " + tokens.get(2));
            }
        }

        // Do some more operations ...
        int value = 0;
        if (StringUtils.isNumeric(tokens.get(2))) {
            value = Integer.parseInt(tokens.get(2));
        }
        // Default value will be 0.
        expression.put(tokens.get(0), value);
    }
    tokens.clear();
}
```